# Find the integral $\int \frac{\left(\sin\left(2 \:x\right)\right)^2}{\left(\sin^3x+\cos^3x\right)^2}$

Tags: integration

That's decided a similar example. This I do not know how to solve. Help me please.[image]

My integral: 
$$\int \frac{\left(sin\left(2 \:x\right)\right)^2}{\left(sin^3x+cos^3x\right)^2}$$

Comment: try the tan half angle substituion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int\frac{(\sin 2x)^2}{(\sin^{3}x+\cos^{3}x)^2}dx=\int\frac{4\sin^2x\cos^2x}{(\sin^{3}x+\cos^{3}x)^2}dx=\int\frac{4\tan^2x\sec^2x}{(\tan^3x+1)^2}dx$

$\hspace{1.8 in}$(after dividing by $\cos^6x$ on the top and bottom).

Now let $u=\tan^3x+1, du=3\tan^2x\sec^2x\;dx$ to get

$\displaystyle\frac{4}{3}\int\frac{1}{u^2}\;du=-\frac{4}{3}\left(\tan^3x+1\right)^{-1}+C$

Comment: wow. how do you come up with this?(+1) too bad, i can upvote only once.

Comment: Thanks - I just tried the techniques I've seen people like you use.

Answer (score 3):

hint: $$\sin(x)^3+\cos(x)^3=(\sin(x)+\cos(x))(1-\sin(x)\cos(x))$$
and $$\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$
i have got this integral
$$\int\,{\frac { \left( {t}^{2}+1 \right)  \left( t-1 \right) ^{2} \left( 
t+1 \right) ^{2}{t}^{2}}{ \left( {t}^{4}+2\,{t}^{3}+2\,{t}^{2}-2\,t+1
 \right) ^{2} \left( {t}^{2}-2\,t-1 \right) ^{2}}}
dt$$

Comment: So I got, what's next?
$$\int \frac{(2sinx \cdot cosx)^{2}}{((sinx+cosx)(1-sinx \cdot cosx))^{2}}dx$$

Comment: use the tan half angle substitution and $\sin(x)$ looks better than $sin(x)$

Comment: I do not understand what to use.

Comment: one moment please i will send you a link

Comment: $\sin(x)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$,$\cos(x)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$

Comment: $dx=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}dt$

Comment: @Sonnhard Grauber
and what to do with the last integral?
Share term by term?

Comment: simplify the integrand

Comment: This method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner It should be $dx=\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt$